# Mapview fragment type mismatch error

Tags: java, android

I am trying to `define` a fragment with a `mapview`.
My `xml` file is:

**fragment_first.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" >-->

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the `java` code is:

**FirstFragment.java**(copied from google's repo)

```
public class FirstFragment extends FragmentActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_first);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

Now, I am calling this fragment to my **MainActivity** as:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
 ...
    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch (pos) {

                case 0:
                    return FirstFragment.onMapReady();

                default:
                    return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Default");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }
    }
}
```

which is giving me compile time error:

> Error:(105, 41) error: method onMapReady in class FirstFragment cannot
>   be applied to given types; required: GoogleMap found: no arguments
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

What I am going wrong here? One part is obvious about the activity's argument, which I still need to figure out. But what is the error:

> Non-static Method OnMapReady(...) can not be referenced from a static
>   context

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

> Non-static Method OnMapReady(...) can not be referenced from a static context

You need to use *FirstFragment*'s object to call it's method *onMapReady()* because *onMapReady()* is non static.

Comment: I have tried: `FirstFragment newMapFragment = new FirstFragment();
        newMapFragment.onMapReady(location);` with error that cannot resolve onMapReady()

Comment: @BaRud  You are supposed to pass GoogleMap object as expected in implementation:

Comment: True, but here i am getteing error even before the argument is passed(i mean in android studio's code checker).  Can you please show me what to do?